# XPath evaluation in for loop always returns value for node from first Iteration

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to extract values from a node using a method which is invoked within a for loop.

Every time the Method is invoked, the xpath.evaluate only evaluates the original node that was first passed into the method.

-Sample Node

```
<doc>
  <str name="subcategory">xyzabc</str>
  <str name="type">QAs</str>
  <str name="id">1234</str>
</doc>
```

-- for loop where invoked

```
 ArrayList<Node> responseNodeList = parseResponse(*document as string*);   
 for(int k = 0;k<responseNodeList.size();k++){
                Result resultNode = new Result();

                resultNode.setUrl(new URL(getAttributeValue(responseNodeList.get(k),resultUrl)));
                resultNode.setId(new String(getAttributeValue(responseNodeList.get(k),resultId)));
}
```

-- Method where i extract the value

```
private String getAttributeValue(final Node responseNodeUrl, String attribute) throws SearchException {
        try {   
        Node evalNode = null;
        evalNode = responseNodeUrl;

        try {
            nodelisttostr(responseNodeUrl); // This is what i am printing out the node.. where we dont have a problem
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = null;
         expr = xPath.compile("/doc/str[@name='"+attribute+"']");  
        String result ;
        result=(String) expr.evaluate(evalNode,XPathConstants.STRING);  
        xPath.reset();
        System.out.println("++++++++"+result); //But when i print this out, it always prints the same value

        return result;
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        log.error("Error in SearchEngine:getAttributeValue:: "+e.getMessage());
        throw new SearchException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using an absolute xpath (starting with `/`),, try finding one that takes your current node

Comment: Can you show us documentation for `parseResponse()` or tell us what it returns? And what is the form of the "`* document as string *`" that you're parsing ... does it have some sort of top-level element of which the `<doc>` elements are children?

Comment: The parse response method is like this:
`private ArrayList<Node> parseResponse(String string) throws SearchException {
Document responseDoc = formXMLDoc(string.toString());
ArrayList<Node> result= new ArrayList();
  try {
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//"+"doc");  
NodeList nodes;
nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(responseDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
result.add(nodes.item(i));
}
return result;
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) { }
 }`

Comment: The <doc> Tag is a part of <response> Tag, This is actually a response from SOLR search engine, It looks like this `<response> <.......</..> <result> <doc> <str name = "id">123</str> <str name = "content">abc</str> </doc> </result> </response>`
@LarsH the getAttriburteMethod Recieves the parameter as dom.Node

Answer (score 2):

Solved..

The XpathExpression was always picking up the first node passed to the method and for some reason it seemed like it was cached, I changed my evaluation string to look like  `expr = xPath.compile(".//str[@name='"+attribute+"']");`  and then the evaluate method now pics up the current document.

Thank you All.

Answer (score -1):

If on your XML above, you use:

```
//doc/str/@name
```

You will get:

```
Attribute='name="subcategory"'
Attribute='name="type"'
Attribute='name="id"'
```

If you use `contains` in the XPath expression on your XML above i.e.

```
//doc/str/@name[contains(.,'e')]
```

then you will get:

```
Attribute='name="subcategory"'
Attribute='name="type"'
```

But I think you want to just want to do the following with your code:

change this:

```
expr = xPath.compile("/doc/str[@name='"+attribute+"']");
```

to this i.e. add an extra `/`:

```
expr = xPath.compile("//doc/str[@name='"+attribute+"']");
```

To evaluate all nodes instead of just the first.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the same options before Asking the community, it returns the same result.
I am starting to think the problem lies in `XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();`